# show timestamp date in human readable format in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

lets say I'm using mongo.shell and I run db.collection.find().pretty() to get this:

```
{
   "name" : "foo",
   "parent" : "bar",
   "createdDate" : NumberLong("12345678"),
   "modifiedDate" : NumberLong("12345679")
}
```

I want those dates to be something human readable, and I want to be able to get that with the least amount of effort possible.

Is there a way to set my .mongorc.js file to automatically convert those values into human readable dates, maybe by specifying exact fields that I consider date fields?  If not what's the most convenient syntax to add to my find call to quickly convert dates to human readable if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use aggregate and format the date string.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
               name: 1, 
               parent: 1, 
               readableCreatedDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$createdDate" } },
               readableModifiedDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$modifiedDate" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

Note: I have tested a similar case in version 3.2 and I guess it works from version 3.0. In addition, the data type of the Date in my case was ISODate not NumberLong

mongodb document looks like this,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxx"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2016-09-13T08:16:52.915Z"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2016-09-13T08:16:52.915Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```